# Extracting information from PCAP

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep, pcap

the logs are formatted below. there is also brackets around each **.

```
03/16-08:30:05.350000 ** [1:491:8] INFO FTP Bad login ** [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 192.168.21.101:21 -> 192.168.202.102:4061
```

what I am trying to do is:

- extract all destination IPs
- extract source IP/destination IP/port pairs
- view all events associated with source IP and get a count of all destinations from the identified source IP

I have just exctracted all IPs and ports:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\:[0-9]\{3,10\}' alert.pcap | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You can get the ip and port in much shorter and cleaner ways. Although before that, can you post a little more of log file here, in the same structure as you have it. If in case its large, put a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) link to log in you question.

Comment: What has this to do with PCAP (files from a packet capture)? This looks more like some IDS alert logs.

Answer (score 2):

The listing you showed at top appears to be from snort or suricata alert file. And using grep on a pcap file is unlikely to give you what you want.

The right tool for extracting the things you want is probably tshark (the command line version of wireshark).

Extract the destination IPs:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e ip.dst
```

Extract TCP source, destination IPs and ports:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -Y tcp
```

Same for UDP:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e udp.srcport -e ip.dst -e udp.dstport -Y udp
```

Pipe any of the above to `sort -u` to get unique addresses/tuples.

Another option is to produce an all-inclusive listing in a format suitable for loading into a spreadsheet and use spreadsheet functions to slice and dice as you see fit. One such command line would produce a comma-separated-value format:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -E separator=, -T fields -e ip.proto -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e udp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e udp.dstport -Y "udp or tcp"
```

The `ip.proto` column here is 6 for TCP or 17 for UDP. Only the respective src/dst port columns will be populated for each IP sub-protocol.